# Error parsing data with AppleScript and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml, applescript

**Hello,** 
I'm trying to parse some data using `appleScript` and `JSON` helper,
specifically trying to get the value of `src` of the `image` property.

```
 tell application "JSON Helper"
    -- fetch the JSON
    set wallpaperJson to fetch JSON from "https://glowing-torch-5096.firebaseio.com//kimono/api/95cifi2g/latest.json"

    -- pull out the URL
    set wallpaperUrl to src of image of model of results of wallpaperJson
```

**Result,**

> error "Can’t get image of {{image:{alt:\"April by Rich Cutrone on 500px\", src:\"https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/141047085/q%3D80_h%3D300/fa5a7f61529d6e30a31c04edc63ccdec\"}}}." number -1728 from image of {{image:{alt:"April by Rich Cutrone on 500px", src:"https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/141047085/q%3D80_h%3D300/fa5a7f61529d6e30a31c04edc63ccdec"}}}

Here the source **`JSON`**:

```
{"count":1,"lastrunstatus":"success","name":"500HDPic","newdata":true,"results":{"model":[{"image":{"alt":"April by Rich Cutrone on 500px","src":"https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/141047085/q%3D80_h%3D300/fa5a7f61529d6e30a31c04edc63ccdec"}}]},"thisversionrun":"Mon Feb 22 2016 02:26:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)","thisversionstatus":"success","version":1}
```

[image]

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the **model** is a list which contains a record, so the script must get the first item in the **model**.

Like this:

```
set wallpaperJson to {thisversionrun:"Mon Feb 22 2016 02:26:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)", |count|:1, results:{model:{{image:{alt:"April by Rich Cutrone on 500px", src:"https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/141047085/q%3D80_h%3D300/fa5a7f61529d6e30a31c04edc63ccdec"}}}}, newdata:true, thisversionstatus:"success", |version|:1, lastrunstatus:"success", |name|:"500HDPic"}

set wallpaperUrl to src of image of item 1 of (model of results of wallpaperJson)
```

Comment: Thank you very much jackjr300 you are my personal hero. Just wonder why you used the parenthesis.. "(model of results of wallpaperJson)" what that means and where do I need to use it? Thanks you very much for your help and time!

Comment: It's just an habit. Sometimes it's necessary, as the **selection** command  of the **Finder** : `item 1 of selection`doesn't work, `item 1 of (get selection)` work